# _.debounce doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to use lodash [debounce()](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) function. Here is the simplest example.

```
var update_from = function (name) {
            console.log(name);
 };
$( document ).ready(function() {
  _.debounce(update_from, 1500)("first");
  _.debounce(update_from, 1500)('second');
  _.debounce(update_from, 1500)("third");
});
```

I expect only "third" to be printed into console. But all three are printed.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding? According this [article](http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation), this should work like I expect, but it doesn't.

Here is plunkr with that example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OCDAChkMes97XcMLJSag?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating and executing three separate debounced functions, not one debounced function three times.

```
var myFunc = _.debounce(update_from, 1500);
myFunc('first');
myFunc('second');
myFunc('third');
```

Comment: @Aldarund :-) Certainly been there myself.